# $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

When I am trying to use  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg it showing me not a function error

I am loading my JS scripts as following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tmpl.1.0.0pre.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = true;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "none";
    $.mobile.minScrollBack = 250;
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme = "f";
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile.easydialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile.autocomplete.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ui.stars.min.3.0.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.2.67.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.colorbox-1.3.16.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cycle.all.2.9999.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
```

How can I resolve this.

Comment: 1) use jQuery 1.9 with jQM 1.4 2) `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg` is removed in jQM 1.4, replacement is `$.mobile.loading("show OR hide")`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.mobile.loading('show', {
    theme: "a",
    text: msg,
    textonly: true,
    textVisible: true
});
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/

Comment: In the text : msg use user " text message". It's working...$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg may be deprecated in jqm 1.4.5 version